# How to use "any()" in a grouped data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a database with several observations of an object at different times, at which an event can occur or not.

I want to know for every object if there is or will be an event.

Here is an example :

```
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
z=c(NA,NA,NA,F,NA,NA,F,F,T)
df=data.frame(object=x, time=y, event=z)
```

Expected output is `Object 1 = NA`, `Object 2 = FALSE` and `Object 3 = TRUE`

Here is my attempts :

```
df %>% group_by(object) %>% summarise(any(event==T, na.rm=F)) 
#Object 2 = NA

df %>% group_by(object) %>% summarise(any(event==T, na.rm=T))
#Object 1 = FALSE
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
df %>%
   group_by(object) %>% 
   summarise(Col = as.logical(any(event, na.rm = TRUE)* NA^(all(is.na(event)))) )
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  object   Col
#   <dbl> <lgl>
#1      1    NA
#2      2 FALSE
#3      3  TRUE
```

Comment: akrun saves the day like always

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(split(df$event, df$object), function(x)
    ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, as.logical(max(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
#    1     2     3 
#   NA FALSE  TRUE
```